# How to perform a function by screen size javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to perform a function by screen size javascript/bootstrap?

this is the div : 
`<div className="col-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>`

and i want to set this function (only in small screen) :
`const [ navOpen, setNavOpen ] = useState(true)`

the code is in reactjs, how can i call a function when the screen is small?

Comment: [Window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) might be a good option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you'd be much better off with a `useEffect` built around [Window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) than something using `innerWidth`. This is the JavaScript equivalent of css media queries. That way you're using something event-driven.

Something like this maybe:

```
const [ navOpen, setNavOpen ] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  const x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
  function myFunction(e) {
    setNavOpen(false);
  };
  x.addListener(myFunction)
  return () => x.removeListener(myFunction);
}, []);
```

Note: since it's got an event listener, note there is a clean up function being returned to remove the listener.

credit: I copied part of my code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp)

Edit: adding empty dependency array on recommendation of @agus-zubiaga

Comment: I agree. However, I think this code has a bug. If the user manually opened the nav, and their screen matches the media query, this hook will immediately close it because it runs on every render. I would pass an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for windows width and height in a useEffect and set your nav open or close for example.

```
useEffect({
    const width = windows.innerWidth;
    const height = windows.innerHeight;
    if(height <= 720 && width <= 420){
      setNavOpen(true)
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.innerHeight` to calculate your `useState` default value:

```
const [ navOpen, setNavOpen ] = useState(window.innerWidth > 320)
```

However, if the Nav should open and close automatically when the screen is resized. You can use [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) which allows you to react to screen dimensions.

If this is a one-off, you can use it directly in a `useEffect` hook like in [David784's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60802929/4014467).

In my case, since I work on a big app with many components that need to react to screen size, I use a library called [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive). It simplifies media queries in React.